# Http proxy server performance analyzing

Tags: performance, proxy, load-testing, http-proxy, stress-testing

I have implemented a http proxy client/server. Currently I intended to test performance of this proxy client/server. Can anybody tell me what kind of tests should I take to analyze it's performance? Which aspects and how I can analyze several aspects of it's performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that first thing you should do is to stress your proxy to determine its maximum throughput and see if there are any issues like segfaults, memory leaks, how does it scale (if it does), etc.

In order to put it under the load you'll need a load testing tool.

The best free and open-source options as for now are:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide to determine the most appropriate one for your scenario.

You can also take a look into performance tests of popular proxy servers like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/test/) or [sqiud](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/PerformanceAnalysis), hopefully it will safe some of your valuable time.

Comment: I decided to use tsung for this mean. Actually currently I cant configure tsung to load testing the proxy server. I started client and server on a machine called localhost. client listen to traffic on a specified port and check for requested web addresses by users.
 If the requested address has been defined in client list, client redirect connection to the server, otherwise connect it to requested address directly. Do you know how I can configure tsung to do this?

Comment: See [Benchmarking a proxy server](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/benchmark.html#benchmarking-a-proxy-server) chapter of Tsung documentation. You need to add the following option: `<option type="ts_http" name="http_use_server_as_proxy" value="true"></option>`